# Clobber list in gcc inline assembly

Tags: gcc, inline-assembly, low-level

I have read some resources about gcc inline assembly (including the manual of gcc itself) and I have not seen in any of them a specific statement about how the compiler operates when the asm code has clobbering list.

Does he saves all the registers in the clobbering list on the stack before entering the asm code and after it, he just pops them back?

Thanks a lot to the helpers.

Comment: The compiler will do whatever it takes to ensure that any register that is marked as clobbered doesn't have its value used after (without being reinitialized). The optimizer is pretty smart. It can often use different registers to avoid picking one that will be clobbered. In theory in the worst case they could be saved and restored to/from the stack.

Comment: I guess the compiler does that also for the registers that being used for saving output parameters and input parameters?

Comment: Yes, anything that appears as output, input/output, or clobbered will force the compiler to ensure that the data in those registers is not relied on after the inline assembly statement.

Comment: If something is listed **only** as an input parameter, the compiler assumes the data in the register before the inline assembly is the same after and doesn't have to do anything to preserve it if it chooses not to.